# How to change Slider label colour in Flutter?

Tags: constructor, flutter

Is it possible to change the Slider label colour in Flutter?

There is no such field in constructor of `Slider` class.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to Flutter api use valueIndicatorColor which is the property of SliderThemeData As mention here [SliderClass](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Slider-class.html)
and here [SliiderThemeData](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliderThemeData-class.html)

Simple Demonstration:
set local variables:

```
double feet = 0;
String heightInFeet = "null";
int height = 180;
```

and Here comes your Custom Slider Solution

```
SliderTheme(
                  data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
                    valueIndicatorColor: Colors.blue, // This is what you are asking for
                    inactiveTrackColor: Color(0xFF8D8E98), // Custom Gray Color
                    activeTrackColor: Colors.white,
                    thumbColor: Colors.red,
                    overlayColor: Color(0x29EB1555),  // Custom Thumb overlay Color
                    thumbShape:
                        RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 12.0),
                    overlayShape:
                        RoundSliderOverlayShape(overlayRadius: 20.0),
                  ),
                  child: Slider(
                    value: height.toDouble(),
                    onChanged: (double newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        height = newValue.toInt();
                        feet = (height / 30.48);
                        heightInFeet = feet.toStringAsFixed(2) + " feet";
                      });
                    },
                    divisions: 220,
                    label: heightInFeet,
                    min: 90.0,
                    max: 305.0,
                  ),
                )
```

and if you want to change Text color text font etc. use

```
valueIndicatorTextStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.amber, letterSpacing: 2.0)
```

in SliderThemeData

Comment: Thank you for the concise answer! Just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

that´s one way to do it, but that will change all the placer where  `accentTextTheme` it´s use, you can use this:

```
   Theme(
      child: yourSlide,
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        accentTextTheme: TextTheme(bodyText2: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
      ),
    )
```

This way you will only change the widget you need to change and not the entire `accentTextTheme` that can be use for other that maybe you don't need to change.

Comment: body2 is deprecated. use bodyText2 instead.

Answer (score 3):

Use SliderThemeData:

```dart
sliderTheme: ThemeData.dark().sliderTheme.copyWith(
  valueIndicatorColor: _primaryColor,
  valueIndicatorTextStyle: TextStyle(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent
  )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found that it is specified in `Slider` class above `label` field.

> The label is rendered using the active [ThemeData]'s
> [ThemeData.accentTextTheme.bodyText2] text style.

When creating the `App` widget it is necessary to specify the `accentTextTheme` and the `bodyText2` field.

```
return MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    accentTextTheme: TextTheme(bodyText2: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
  ),
  home: MyHomePage(),
);
```

Comment: body2 is deprecated. Use bodyText2 instead

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this with SliderTheme like this

```dart
SliderTheme(
               data: SliderThemeData(
               valueIndicatorTextStyle: TextStyle(
               color: Colors.red, // Change the label color here
                      ),
                ),
                          child: Slider(
                            value: fontSize.toDouble(),
                            min: 12,
                            max: 18,
                            label: fontSize.toString(),
                          ),
                        ),
```