# Why parent class is accepting color from child?

Tags: flutter, flutter-slider

I'm working on Slider, I want to change the thumb color, but this is not working. thumbColor accepts color from Child:Slider activeColor.

```
SliderTheme(

              data:SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
                // thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 19.0),
                // overlayColor: Colors.grey,
                thumbColor: Colors.white,

              ),
              child: Slider(
                inactiveColor: Colors.transparent,
                min: 0,

                activeColor: Color(0xffF3C961),
                value: value.toDouble(),
                max: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                onChanged: (changedValue){
                  setState(() {

                    value = changedValue.toInt();

                  });
                },
              ),
            ),[![You can check color of thumb shape][1]][1]
```

Comment: what do you mean by *"parent class is accepting color from child"* ?

Comment: I mean property of Parent(SliderTheme) thumbColor is not working, you can check above code, this thumbColor is overriden by property of Child(Slider) activeColor

Comment: it is working, use: `thumbColor: Colors.red,
activeTrackColor: Colors.orange,` inside `copyWith()` and remove `activeColor:` from `Slider`

Comment: i think you are looking for this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/58112299/11033305